# Textfields getting cleared in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am currently creating an application and atm I am at the login and sign up function. I decided to create a tableview where I've textfields so the user can sign up. But every time I enter something in the textfield and scrolls down, the textfields is getting cleared out, but why?

Also, how can I add this data to my database when I tap a button? Since I cannot reach it from there. Any input?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "signUpCell", for: indexPath) as! SignUpTableViewCell

    cell.txtfield.delegate = self
    cell.textOfField.text = textNames[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.txtfield.text = textFields[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]


@IBAction func signUpButtonTapped(_ sender: Any)
{
    let authentication = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    //I know how to add it to the database, but how can I retrieve the tableview data here?

}
```

Comment: Show the code where you update your `textFields` array each time the text in a text field changes.

Comment: I don't have that one yet. Lets create it

Comment: @rmaddy How should I do the update one?

Answer (score 0):

Cells are dequeud you need to update the data source array , this inside `cellForRowAt`

```
 cell.textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
 cell.textField.indexPath = indexPath
```

And

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: CustomTexf) { 
   let index = textField.indexPath
   textFields[index.section][index.row] = textField.text!
}
```

Create this class and assign it to the textfield

```
class CustomTexf : UITextField {
   var indexPath:IndexPath!
}
```

Comment: I would use the `textFieldDidEndEditing` delegate method instead of `textFieldDidChange`. Much simpler and no need to update the data model on every character.

Comment: cell.textField.indexPath does exists.

Comment: @rmaddy yes it's another option also

Comment: @PrezyProgramming make sure you add the above class

Comment: No, do not add an indexPath property to a text field. That is the wrong solution. There are proper ways to determine the index path of a cell from a text field.

Comment: the only other way is acessing the superview of the textfield until the cell itself , then `table.indexpathForCell(cell)` and this depends of how complex your hierarchy

Comment: @rmaddy How do you do it?